# Scoring does not work in the game on the Unity engine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, 3d

I modulate 3d game for android. And scoring dosent work. The very essence is that after removing the cars outside the map, points, top result and coins are nailed. What is the compiler that unity does not issue errors

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreShow : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private Text topRecord;

    void onEnable()
    {
        GetComponent<Text>().text = "Score: " + deletecar.countCars.ToString();
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score") < deletecar.countCars)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", deletecar.countCars);
            topRecord.text = "Top:" + deletecar.countCars.ToString();
        }
        else
            topRecord.text = "Top:" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score").ToString();
    }
}
```

**Part 2 of the code**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class deletecar : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static int countCars;

    void Start()
    {
        countCars = 0;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            if (!Collisoinscars.lose)
            {
                countCars++;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Coins", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coins") + 1);
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be OnEnable() its a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the issue is in this piece of code, where you are enabling the gameobject.

```
void onEnable()
{
    GetComponent<Text>().text = "Score: " + deletecar.countCars.ToString();
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score") < deletecar.countCars)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", deletecar.countCars);
        topRecord.text = "Top:" + deletecar.countCars.ToString();
    }
    else
        topRecord.text = "Top:" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score").ToString();
}
```

It is a typo mistake, the `void onEnable` would be `OnEnable`

Comment: What error message would user get on typo mistake?